# OFFSET n ROWS FETCH NEXT n

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that uses the offset/fetch next for paging:

```
ORDER BY <<CONDTIONS>>
OFFSET 50 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

The problem is this return me the first 50 rows, which make it exactly the same as this:

```
ORDER BY <<CONDTIONS>>
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

Why would this be happening?  The ORDER BY conditions are exactly the same in both case.

Comment: Are you _certain_ that these two queries have identical result sets?

Comment: What makes you think it is returning the first 50 rows? Is it possible that rows 51 - 100 look the same as rows 1 - 50? Note that for OFFSET / FETCH to work reliably the ORDER BY conditions must "contain a column or combination of columns that are guaranteed to be unique".

Comment: You got it Nathan, it turn out the ORDER BY was NOT unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORDER BY must be nique for offset and fetch next to work properly.